# Get return value from swift2 IOS function from javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webview

I have an IOS App which uses Xwebview which loads pages from a web server. On all buttons (on the html pages) I call a function with javascript to the App function. The problem is I cant get a return value to the javascript.

Javascript:

```
function getHref(data) {
 try { href = jsapi.loadHref ( data ); 
                }
catch(err){ }        
}
```

The jsapi is a class inside the view controller which handles all the javascript calls

IOS App side:

```
let jsapi = xjsapi

class xjsapi: NSobject
{

func loadHref(href:String)-> String {
some more code
return "some url"
}
}
```

I have also tried:

```
@objc func getPlatform(callback: XWVScriptObject) {
var myerror: NSError?
callback.call(arguments: ["{\"code\":1}"], error: &myerror) 
}

JavaScript:

window.injectedObj.getPlatform(function(result){ /*your code */});
```

Comment: are you using any javascript bridge for doing this?

Comment: Hi, I am using XWebView Cocoa pod, pod 'XWebView', '~> 0.9.2  All my other jsapi functions from java to the APP functions work ok

Comment: I can print the variable "data" to the debug panel on the App so the javascript is passing the variable...I just need a return from one from the App

Comment: I figured it out my self